# How would I award my own Eureka moment?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, self-answer

Look at this: [Getting depth-first traversal insted of breadth first in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336520/getting-depth-first-traversal-insted-of-breadth-first-in-t-sql)

I struggled a bit with this before I posted it, and couldn't find the answer I was looking for. (I must have had a lapse in my google-skills). I then went for a walk, and when I came back, I almost immediately had an eureka moment, and could answer my own question.

How should I score/award this?

Comment: Go buy yourself a beer. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After two days of posting the question, you can accept your own answer as the one which solved the question. Note that this won't award you with 15 reputation, but it will mark the question as solved.

Comment: It also won't award you with 2 reputation for accepting the answer.