# Should I delete my question and answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, self-answer

I've posted this question earlier today:

[After installing Xcode 7, Xcode 6.3 shows errors about converting to Swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752203/after-installing-xcode-7-xcode-6-3-shows-errors-about-converting-to-swift-2)

Then a comment helped me find the solution, so I made a little answer myself to confirm it was indeed the way to go.

But it's not a programming problem per se, and now I'm not sure my question/answer would help anybody else as it was a specific problem, and I don't want to leave cruft on the site.

So should I delete everything, or leave it and accept my answer later?

*Note: I'm aware of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252491/how-would-i-award-my-own-eureka-moment) about accepting own's answer, but I'm still not sure what to do.*

Comment: Well, it's a question about a programming tool, so it would be on topic.  I couldn't comment on whether or not it'd be useful to others though.

Comment: Questions about misbehaving programming tools are on topic, even if the answer doesn't have anything to do with programming.  It very rarely ever does.  Mark the Q+A as answered as soon as you can, it will take 2 days.

Comment: Don't see any problems with that question and self-answer. I assume others may come across a similar problem if they did as you did. The only thing I would add is any specific errors that people experiencing the same issue might see, or any other terms that would make searching for your post easier.

Comment: Thank you for your coments and answers. I will follow @ryanyuyu's advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about tools related to programming, so it's still probably on-topic.  I'm not exactly sure what details are needed to make installation problems specific (MVCE), but you seem to provide enough information to make the problem clear.  I'd personally make a few edits (removing the meta-commentary about deletion for example) and accept your own answer when your 48 hour restriction for self-accepting is over.

If you can somehow find an answered duplicate, you can also close your question.  Otherwise, it's still a useful question and answer and should remain on the site.