# Should I delete my probably useless question?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

Should I delete [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227469/bluetooth-low-energy-advertising-data-restriction-in-windows-10-api/40241456#40241456) since the answer was embarrassingly simple to the point of probably not being ever helpful to anyone? This is very similar to [this case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296559/should-i-delete-my-question-and-answer), except that I think my question has less potential to be useful...

Comment: How exactly did you miscount the number of bytes? If there is logic to it then that might make for a more worthwhile answer. Right now what tips me to the "delete it" side of things is because of the current state of the answer only.

Comment: @Gimby I literally had a `byte[]` which I had manually initialized with values... I was using a repeating pattern (`0123456789ABCDEF`) and repeated more than intended. :)

Comment: It's upvoted, which counts against an autoban, but if you delete it, it might count towards one. Part of the autoban calculation considers "wasting other people's time".  I'd wager deleting upvoted content also is considered bad by the autoban algo.

Comment: @Will At this point I'm fairly apathetic, so if you're saying I *shouldn't* delete it...?

Comment: Don't delete.  It can only harm your account standing.

Comment: @Will Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: Nah.  I can't answer definitively about the harm, just that I strongly suspect it would harm without any benefit.

Comment: @Will On the other hand, deleting it would reward the Disciplined badge, so we're encouraging this behavior in a way.

Comment: Well, if you were to ask a flat out BAD question, you could always delete to get the badge. It's one of my few ;) 

Peer Pressure

Delete own post with score of -3 or lower

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally, a question like this will be closed with the following reason:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

If the question is closed and both the score of the question and the answer are zero or less, it will be eventually be deleted by the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). You're welcome to delete it yourself, though, precisely because of the reasons you mention.

Comment: _"Because the question has an answer, it will not be deleted by the Roomba. "_ Even with a zero score answer?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not sure - I couldn't find a complete list of triggers for Roomba.

Comment: @yellowantphil thanks, I stand corrected. That also explains why I couldn't find a Meta thread - it is in the help center.

Comment: I guess I'll just wait for Roomba, given the remarks about potential autoban concerns.

Answer (score 3):

If there's some flaw in the API that you were using that might lead a lot of other people to make the same mistake, go ahead and leave the question. If that's unlikely, and you just didn't have enough (or too much) coffee, go ahead and delete it.

Comment: More specifically, this question is what happened when I tried to switch to tea...