# Accidentally answered my question right after asking it

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-questions, self-answer

So, I asked a question about a kind of awkward data structure massaging I was trying to do in `python`. I usually play around with solutions while asking the question, as well as after I write it, just because I don't like relying on StackOverflow 100%

This time I accidentally found the answer very soon (~2 min) after asking the question. I got a couple of upvotes, but something doesn't feel quite right about it. Should I delete the question if I don't need help anymore?

[Question for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394394/concatenating-list-results-from-multiple-functions/31394433#31394433)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with self-answered questions. At least if they are basically ok. It's even encouraged.

Comment: No.It may be helpful for others

Comment: Also a good one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252491/how-would-i-award-my-own-eureka-moment